# Proving some coset stuff (should be easy)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

Let $H$ be the set of all permutations in $S_7$ with fixed points at 1, and $T$ be the set of all permutations in $S_7$ that send 1 to 2. Let $\sigma = (1234567)$. Prove $T = \sigma H$.

I've shown $\sigma H \subseteq T$, and am trying to show containment the other way. How do I show that any permutation that sends 1 to 2 can be written as $(1234567)\mu$ where $\mu \in H$?

Comment: Hint. Look at $(1234567)(12)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you've shown that $\sigma H\subseteq T$, all you need to do now is to note that $T$ and $H$, have the same number of elements ($6!$).  And $H$ and $\sigma H$ also have the same number of elements.

Comment: How do we know that $H$ and $\sigma H$ have the same number of elements?

Comment: ah $H$ is a subgroup of $S_7$, so a bijection exists. never mind!

Comment: @mkl846 actually, this has nothing to do with the fact that $H$ is a subgroup. $H$ and $\sigma H$ have the same number of elements because $h\in H\mapsto \sigma h\in \sigma H$ defines a bijection.